# Linux: Is there handy way to exec a program binding it to IP-address of choice?

Tags: linux, freebsd, ip, lxc, jails

In FreeBSD 4.9 it was very easy to accomplish with just a single command like

```
jail [-u username]  path hostname ip-number command
```

if path was `/` you had running just the same program as usual but all its network communication was restricted to use only given IP-address as the source. Sometimes it's very handy.

Now in Linux there's LXC, which does look very similar to FreeBSD's `jail` (or Solaris' zones) — can you think of similar way to execute a program?

Comment: What program are you trying to do this with? Many programs are configurable enough that they can be *told* which IP to bind to.

Comment: @WarrenYoung, Thanks K. O., but "many" != "all"

Comment: A good use case for "jailing" an executable to use a specific IP is running multiple game servers on one machine on a LAN party. E.g. Valve games are only broadcasting on ports 27015-27020 so per IP you can only have 6 servers. So you add virtual IP's on a NIC but then you need to specify "+ip <address>" on the game server's command line which stops broadcasting its presence to clients => no servers visible in LAN browser. So "+ip" won't work. Therefore we need to jail each server in an environment where it can only find 1 IP address. Result: no limit in #servers + clients see all servers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting the process inside a [network namespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html) that can only see the desired IP address can accomplish something similar.  For instance, supposed I only wanted localhost available to a particular program.

First, I create the network namespace:

```
ip netns add limitednet
```

Namespaces have a loopback interface by default, so next I just need to bring it up:

```
sudo ip netns exec limitednet ip link set lo up
```

Now, I can run a program using `ip netns exec limitednet` and it will only be able to see the loopback interface:

```
sudo ip netns exec limitednet ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If I wanted to limit it to an address other than localhost, I could add other interfaces into the namespace using:

```
ip link set DEVICE_NAME netns NAMESPACE
```

I'd have to experiment a bit more to figure out how to add a single IP address into a namespace in the case where an interface might have more than one IP address

The [LWN article on namespaces](http://lwn.net/Articles/580893/) is also helpful.

Comment: But it's worth mentioning it would require much more preparations since network namespace has its own routing table and so on. If somebody comes with simpler way to mimic `jail`, I'm gonna use it. ;)